# DecisionTreeRegression gives 100% training accuracy but fails in test set

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I am trying to fit a really small dataset which has no of training example=16 and when I used decision tree regression although it gives exact values in training but fails in test set. I cant figure out why it is happening

```py
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor

model = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=50,max_features="auto")

model.fit(X, Y)
```

Comment: How exactly it fails?

Comment: By _it fails_ do you actually mean that you get low accuracy?

Comment: ... or an error? or what?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that by *"it fails in test set"* you actually mean that you get a low testing accuracy.

---

This is a perfect example of an **overfitted model**. By definition, overfitting occurs when the training accuracy (in your case is 100%) is greater than the training/validation accuracy. This means that your model has learned patterns in the training data which are not applicable or valid in the wider population.

---

There are many techniques that can help you tackle overfitting. It might be worth starting with *K-Fold Validation*.